# PL/SQL error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION"

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration, error-handling

I'm making a PL/SQL error handling template. I'm getting this error: 'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION"' and I can't figure out what's wrong. We're using an Oracle database.

```
DECLARE
err_num VARCHAR(100); -- We're not gonna do math on this so I made it a string.
err_msg VARCHAR2(100);
program  VARCHAR2(100);
statement VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
program := 'assign the program here';
statment := 'assign the statement here';
END;


EXCEPTION


WHEN ACCESS_INTO_NULL
THEN
err_num := SQLCODE;
err_msg := SQLERRM(SQLCODE);
comment := "assign a comment here";
INSERT INTO ERRORS VALUES (err_num, err_msg, program, statement, comment, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

WHEN CASE_NOT_FOUND
THEN
err_num := SQLCODE;
err_msg := SQLERRM(SQLCODE);
comment := "assign a comment here";
INSERT INTO ERRORS VALUES (err_num, err_msg, program, statement, comment, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

...

WHEN OTHERS
THEN
err_num := -9999;
err_msg := 'undefined error occurred';
comment := "assign a comment here";
INSERT INTO ERRORS VALUES (err_num, err_msg, program, statement, comment, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);


END;
```

The ERRORS table is:

```
CREATE TABLE ERRORS 
(
  ERR_NUM VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ERR_MSG VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, PROGRAM VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, STATEMENT VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, USER_COMMENT VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, TIMESTAMP DATE NOT NULL 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE DATAL03 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL;
```

Comment: What do you expect the `EXCEPTION` keyword to map to?  It's not part of the PL/SQL block above it.  Is it embedded in an outer PL/SQL block that isn't mentioned here?  Where are your exceptions defined?  `access_into_null` and `case_not_found` aren't built-in exceptions.  Perhaps you've defined them in that same outer block?  And why wouldn't you use the `sqlcode` and/or `sqlerrm` functions in your `others` block?

Comment: I'm new to this - thanks for the input. 

How can I make the `EXCEPTION` keyword map to that block? I thought it had. I want it to handle exceptions raised in the `BEGIN` and `DECLARE` above it.

I'll modify it with the stuff you said about the others block.

[dba-oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_built_in_plsql_exceptions.htm) says that `access_into_null` and `case_not_found` are built-in, is that wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's `DECLARE ... BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END;`

Comment: Right. remove the first `END;` and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others advised in the comments, all what you need to do is remove the first `END` as follows:

```
DECLARE
err_num VARCHAR(100); -- We're not gonna do math on this so I made it a string.
err_msg VARCHAR2(100);
program  VARCHAR2(100);
statement VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
program := 'assign the program here';
statment := 'assign the statement here';



EXCEPTION


WHEN ACCESS_INTO_NULL
THEN
err_num := SQLCODE;
err_msg := SQLERRM(SQLCODE);
comment := "assign a comment here";
INSERT INTO ERRORS VALUES (err_num, err_msg, program, statement, comment,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

WHEN CASE_NOT_FOUND
THEN
err_num := SQLCODE;
err_msg := SQLERRM(SQLCODE);
comment := "assign a comment here";
INSERT INTO ERRORS VALUES (err_num, err_msg, program, statement, comment, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

...

WHEN OTHERS
THEN
err_num := -9999;
err_msg := 'undefined error occurred';
comment := "assign a comment here";
INSERT INTO ERRORS VALUES (err_num, err_msg, program, statement, comment, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);


END;
```

Exception section should be part of your PL/SQL block and not a separate part. That said, it should be enclosed within `BEGIN` & `END` statements of PL/SQL block

[Reference](http://www.zentut.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-block-structure/)